# Erlang spawn process error (artificial neural network)

Tags: process, erlang

Hi Erlang beginner here trying to implement a basic ANN (artificial neural network) following [this tutorial](http://erlangcentral.org/wiki/index.php?title=Erlang_and_Neural_Networks#Getting_your_learn_on) from Wil Chung. The code is exactly as in his [github repo](https://github.com/iamwilhelm/erlang_ann).

Running this:

> 1> ann_test:run().

causes a bunch (five to be precise) errors like this:

> =ERROR REPORT==== 18-Feb-2015::07:11:49 
>   === Error in process <0.60.0> with exit value: {undef,[{ann,perceptron,[[],[],[]],[]}]}
>   =ERROR REPORT==== 18-Feb-2015::07:11:49 
>   === Error in process <0.61.0> with exit value: {undef,[{ann,perceptron,[[],[],[]],[]}]}

Somehow spawning the processes here in *ann_test.erl*:

> X1_pid = spawn(ann, perceptron, [[],[],[]]),

causes the trouble but I'm not sure how to trace it. Tried locating the issue with redbug pointing it at *ann_test:run* and *ann:perceptron* but it doesn't show anything. Also tried adding *process_flag(trap_exit, true)* into run() but nothing again. Also tried adding *-compile(export_all)* just in case.

Could anyone point me into right direction? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is bugged. This error means that there is no exported function `ann:perceptron/3` which matches arguments. There is only `ann:perceptron/4`. It is used properly in `ann_test:setup/0` so to fix it, just add another empty list:

```
run() -> 
  ann_graph:start(),
  X1_pid = spawn(ann, perceptron, [[],[],[]]),
  X2_pid = spawn(ann, perceptron, [[],[],[]]),
  H1_pid = spawn(ann, perceptron, [[],[],[]]),
  H2_pid = spawn(ann, perceptron, [[],[],[]]),

  O_pid = spawn(ann, perceptron,  [[],[],[]]),
```

change to:

```
run() -> 
  ann_graph:start(),
  X1_pid = spawn(ann, perceptron, [[],[],[],[]]),
  X2_pid = spawn(ann, perceptron, [[],[],[],[]]),
  H1_pid = spawn(ann, perceptron, [[],[],[],[]]),
  H2_pid = spawn(ann, perceptron, [[],[],[],[]]),

  O_pid = spawn(ann, perceptron,  [[],[],[],[]]),
```

Note that this code doesn't clean after execution and there are errors after eventual re-execution in the same session. To kill registered process `ann_grapher` you can use `exit(whereis(ann_grapher), kill).`

Comment: Not sure how I missed this but thank you very much for your help. It works now. Also thanks re killing processes, already stumbled on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can read this error message `{undef,[{ann,perceptron,[[],[],[]],[]}]}` this way:

- there is no function (`undef`)
- in module `ann`
- called `perceptron`
- that takes three arguments, which all are empty lists `[[], [], []]`

And that is correct, because there is only one definition, which takes 4 arguments, not three. In `ann_test:setup`, `perceptron` is spawned with four empty lists. You could try that.

In other words, the tuple inside the error massege has structure `{Module, Function, ListOfArguments, NotSureWhatThatIs}`

Comment: Many thanks for your help and for explanation of how to read the error message. Added another "[]" and it works now.